# WPF app not interacting with my Windows service

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, windows-services

I have a windows service which needs to open a WPF application based on an event.
I am done with coding and when I run a WPF application instance through a process from my custom window service then it opens the app but hidden to me.

I confirmed it's existence from task manager where my app instance has been created but APP GUI not visible to me.

I also tried using "ProcessExtensions" class available on Github but that didn't help.

Please suggest what should I do for this!

Some saying for IPC mechanism but that I don't wanna use. Please let me know how can I achieve it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Run WPF application from Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793088/c-sharp-run-wpf-application-from-windows-service)

Comment: Make sure to read the comments on the dupe question.

Comment: You should **NOT** run GUI from service in any cases. Services moved to user session 0 for a very good reason. But if you don't care about security and stability of your app, you may start your readings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services).

Comment: @Parth Pandya: CreateProcessAsUser extension class not working for me. Could be duplicate post but not satisfactory reply overthere. Thanks!